# Set Value of Private Static Field

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection

I want to set the value of a private field using reflection for unit testing.

Problem is, that field is static.

Here's what I'm working from:

```
/**
   * Use to set the value of a field you don't have access to, using reflection, for unit testing.
   * 
   * Returns true/false for success/failure.
   * 
   * @param p_instance an object to set a private field on
   * @param p_fieldName the name of the field to set
   * @param p_fieldValue the value to set the field to
   * @return true/false for success/failure
   */
  public static boolean setPrivateField(final Object p_instance, final String p_fieldName, final Object p_fieldValue) {
    if (null == p_instance)
      throw new NullPointerException("p_instance can't be null!");
    if (null == p_fieldName)
      throw new NullPointerException("p_fieldName can't be null!");

    boolean result = true;

    Class<?> klass = p_instance.getClass();

    Field field = null;
    try {
      field = klass.getDeclaredField(p_fieldName);

      field.setAccessible(true);
      field.set(p_instance, p_fieldValue);

    } catch (SecurityException e) {
      result = false;
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
      result = false;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      result = false;
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
      result = false;
    }

    return result;
  }
```

I realize this has probably already been answered on SO, but my search didn't turn it up...

Comment: The obvious answer is "Jasus, don't mutate statics or privates of other classes." You could try Parameterisation from Above.

Comment: if you are using spring you could set @Autowired on a private field, then if you need to replace that instance with a mock you need to change that using reflection from the test method

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Basically the problem is your utility method, which assumes you have an instance. It's reasonably easy to set a private static field - it's exactly the same procedure as for an instance field, except you specify `null` as the instance. Unfortunately your utility method uses the instance to get the class, and requires it to be non-null...

I'd echo Tom's caveat: don't do that. If this is a class you have under your control, I'd create a package level method:

```
void setFooForTesting(Bar newValue)
{
    foo = newValue;
}
```

However, here's a complete sample if you *really, really* want to set it with reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class FieldContainer
{
    private static String woot;

    public static void showWoot()
    {
        System.out.println(woot);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    // Declared to throw Exception just for the sake of brevity here
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Field field = FieldContainer.class.getDeclaredField("woot");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(null, "New value");
        FieldContainer.showWoot();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think unit testing shouldn't push us to do anything in production classes as you state with: I'd create a package level method

Answer (score 7):

Just pass `null` for the object-instance argument. So:

```
field.set(null, p_fieldValue);
```

This will let you set the static field.