# Constant field gets initialized only once under Junit5

Tags: java, constants, junit5

We are migrating to JUnit5 and removing PowerMockito since Mockito now supports mockStatic. Before, PowerMockito offered Whitebox.setInternalState(..) making it possible to set values final fields (constants)
I have a class like

```
public class MyClass {
    
    private static final String myField = Props.getString("myField");
    
    public boolean myMethod() {
        //uses my field
    }
    
}
```

and my Test looks like this

```
class MyClassTest {

    @Test
    void myTest() {
        try (MockedStatic<Props> propsMockedStatic = Mockito.mock(Props.class)) {
            propsMockedStatic.when(() -> Props.getString("myField")).thenReturn("Hello!!");
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
            //more code
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I introduce more tests I see that the `myField` gets mocked only once when I run the Tests although I use a new instance every time. This results in braking tests since on other cases I want `myField` to have different values but when I run them separately everything completes successfully

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234742/resetting-static-fields-for-junit-tests

Comment: Non-Answer: consider changing your production code. Do not try to use mocking frameworks with static methods or fields. The static stuff just makes your code 10 times **harder to test**, for unit tests, but also for any other sort of test you might want to do. Seriously: instead of learning how to use Mockito for static stuff, rather ask yourself how you can improve your production code to be **easy to test**, so that you avoid the whole static-mocking stuff completely. (I have been there with powermock(ito), and rest assured: it is a world of pain. Do not enter)

Comment: In our case: instead of pulling the actual property value, why not make the **key** `myField` your constant, and then any code that needs the property value, just reads it from that Props object? When it is not a real compile time **constant**, why do you force yourself to treat it like one?

Comment: "Constant field gets initialized only once under Junit5" and more generally in Java. This is how static initialization works.

Comment: @AndyTurner ofc I understand why this happens. Previously we were using PowerMockito which offerer Whitebox making it easy to mock such final fields by using Whitebox.setInternalState(..). What I want to do is a walkaround so this can work in JUnit5 and mockito 4.6. Thanks for the answers but the production code cannot be changed just for a unit test to work.

Comment: The point is to change the production code to make the unit test to work. The point is to improve your production code so that it becomes easier to test and doesn't need expensive band aids every time some other code needs to deal with it.

Comment: And note: Whitebox was always in the org.mockito.**internal** ... that is what I am talking about: at some point, you wrote hard to test code. You worked around by using a feature that said right in its name "maybe better not use me". And now you are in trouble. Of course, you can continue to go down this route, and put band aids on the symptoms. Paying the price every time you do so.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answers, I get your point, but I thought of asking if someone has dealt with something similar and achieved to do that without modifying the production code of a legacy project.

Comment: Also, is it a bad practice to have a constant filled like this? I think that's what we want to achieve. After all it's just a string

Comment: Think about it: you made something a constant ... but you have the urgent need to change its value during the life time of the corresponding class. As said before: if your code does different things based on the content of that field, then the inability to change that value hampers more than just the unit tests.

Comment: _ without modifying the production code of a legacy project._ - test classes are not production code.

Answer (score -2):

A temporary workaround that I found on a Stack overflow post is this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043252/17984773. It works with JDK17, Junit5, and Mockito 4.6. Answering that here in case someone searches for the same issue, for me it took a lot of time to bump into this answer. It may be temporary but for now it works

To sum up, what worked for me was opening access to some of the packages as can be seen bellow. To find exact what packages need to be included here, I just run the test each time and error by error I created this array

```
test {
test.jvmArgs = ["--add-exports","java.base/jdk.internal.access=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-exports","java.base/sun.security.jca=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-exports","java.xml/jdk.xml.internal=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-exports","java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-opens","java.base/sun.security.util=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-opens","java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-opens","java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-opens","java.base/java.security.cert=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-opens","java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-opens","java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-opens","java.sql/java.sql=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-opens","java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-opens","java.base/java.util.regex=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-opens","java.base/java.util.stream=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-opens","java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-opens","java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED",
                "--add-opens","java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED"]
}
```

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer instead of posting links to other questions. If this question is a duplicate of the other, please flag it as such