# How can I access the constructor of the constructor I'm using while still maintaining the type

Tags: java, constructor, minecraft

I'm a buildding minecraft modder as of about 18 hours ago. I'm trying to create an item which is of type `ItemPickaxe`, but would also like to be able to modify a parameter in the `ItemPickaxe`'s super constructor that's not one of the parameters for `ItemPickaxe`. Here's an explanation with code as the above makes little sense.

Here is the `ItemPickaxe` class constructor:

```
public class ItemPickaxe extends ItemTool
{
    protected ItemPickaxe(Item.ToolMaterial material)
    {
        super(2.0F, material, field); // 2.0F is an efficiency, material is the material, and field is a set of blocks that the tool works on.

    }
}
```

This is the `ItemTool` class constructor:

```
public class ItemTool extends Item
{

protected ItemTool(float p_i45333_1_, Item.ToolMaterial p_i45333_2_, Set p_i45333_3_)
{
    this.toolMaterial = p_i45333_2_;
    this.field_150914_c = p_i45333_3_;
    this.maxStackSize = 1;
    this.setMaxDamage(p_i45333_2_.getMaxUses());
    this.efficiencyOnProperMaterial = p_i45333_2_.getEfficiencyOnProperMaterial();
    this.damageVsEntity = p_i45333_1_ + p_i45333_2_.getDamageVsEntity();
    this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabTools);
    if (this instanceof ItemPickaxe)
    {
        toolClass = "pickaxe";
    }
    else if (this instanceof ItemAxe)
    {
        toolClass = "axe";
    }
    else if (this instanceof ItemSpade)
    {
        toolClass = "shovel";
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create a class that `extends itemTool` with `toolClass = "pickaxe"` and a custom set (the third parameter in the `ItemTool` constructor), but the `toolClass` string is a `private` variable. How can I create either

1. a class extending `ItemPickaxe` and but still pass the set in the constructor to it's `ItemTool` constructor
2. a class extending `ItemTool` and have `toolClass = "pickaxe"`

`ItemPickaxe` and `ItemTool` can't be modified by me. Otherwise I would have made the `toolClass` variable public.

The rest of the `ItemTool` class was requested, and is as follows.

```
package net.minecraft.item;


public class ItemTool extends Item
{
    private Set field_150914_c;
    protected float efficiencyOnProperMaterial = 4.0F;
    /** Damage versus entities. */
    private float damageVsEntity;
    /** The material this tool is made from. */
    protected Item.ToolMaterial toolMaterial;
    private static final String __OBFID = "CL_00000019";
    protected ItemTool(float p_i45333_1_, Item.ToolMaterial p_i45333_2_, Set p_i45333_3_)
{
    this.toolMaterial = p_i45333_2_;
    this.field_150914_c = p_i45333_3_;
    this.maxStackSize = 1;
    this.setMaxDamage(p_i45333_2_.getMaxUses());
    this.efficiencyOnProperMaterial = p_i45333_2_.getEfficiencyOnProperMaterial();
    this.damageVsEntity = p_i45333_1_ + p_i45333_2_.getDamageVsEntity();
    this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabTools);
    if (this instanceof ItemPickaxe)
    {
        toolClass = "pickaxe";
    }
    else if (this instanceof ItemAxe)
    {
        toolClass = "axe";
    }
    else if (this instanceof ItemSpade)
    {
        toolClass = "shovel";
    }
}

public float func_150893_a(ItemStack p_150893_1_, Block p_150893_2_)
{
    return this.field_150914_c.contains(p_150893_2_) ? this.efficiencyOnProperMaterial : 1.0F;
}

/**
 * Current implementations of this method in child classes do not use the entry argument beside ev. They just raise
 * the damage on the stack.
 */
public boolean hitEntity(ItemStack p_77644_1_, EntityLivingBase p_77644_2_, EntityLivingBase p_77644_3_)
{
    p_77644_1_.damageItem(2, p_77644_3_);
    return true;
}

public boolean onBlockDestroyed(ItemStack p_150894_1_, World p_150894_2_, Block p_150894_3_, int p_150894_4_, int p_150894_5_, int p_150894_6_, EntityLivingBase p_150894_7_)
{
    if ((double)p_150894_3_.getBlockHardness(p_150894_2_, p_150894_4_, p_150894_5_, p_150894_6_) != 0.0D)
    {
        p_150894_1_.damageItem(1, p_150894_7_);
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Returns True is the item is renderer in full 3D when hold.
 */
@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
public boolean isFull3D()
{
    return true;
}

public Item.ToolMaterial func_150913_i()
{
    return this.toolMaterial;
}

/**
 * Return the enchantability factor of the item, most of the time is based on material.
 */
public int getItemEnchantability()
{
    return this.toolMaterial.getEnchantability();
}

/**
 * Return the name for this tool's material.
 */
public String getToolMaterialName()
{
    return this.toolMaterial.toString();
}

/**
 * Return whether this item is repairable in an anvil.
 */
public boolean getIsRepairable(ItemStack p_82789_1_, ItemStack p_82789_2_)
{
    ItemStack mat = this.toolMaterial.getRepairItemStack();
    if (mat != null && net.minecraftforge.oredict.OreDictionary.itemMatches(mat, p_82789_2_, false)) return true;
    return super.getIsRepairable(p_82789_1_, p_82789_2_);
}

/**
 * Gets a map of item attribute modifiers, used by ItemSword to increase hit damage.
 */
public Multimap getItemAttributeModifiers()
{
    Multimap multimap = super.getItemAttributeModifiers();
    multimap.put(SharedMonsterAttributes.attackDamage.getAttributeUnlocalizedName(), new AttributeModifier(field_111210_e, "Tool modifier", (double)this.damageVsEntity, 0));
    return multimap;
}

/*===================================== FORGE START =================================*/
private String toolClass;
@Override
public int getHarvestLevel(ItemStack stack, String toolClass)
{
    int level = super.getHarvestLevel(stack, toolClass);
    if (level == -1 && toolClass != null && toolClass.equals(this.toolClass))
    {
        return this.toolMaterial.getHarvestLevel();
    }
    else
    {
        return level;
    }
}

@Override
public Set<String> getToolClasses(ItemStack stack)
{
    return toolClass != null ? ImmutableSet.of(toolClass) : super.getToolClasses(stack);
}

@Override
public float getDigSpeed(ItemStack stack, Block block, int meta)
{
    if (ForgeHooks.isToolEffective(stack, block, meta))
    {
        return efficiencyOnProperMaterial;
    }
    return super.getDigSpeed(stack, block, meta);
}
/*===================================== FORGE END =================================*/
}
```

Comment: Have you tried overloading the constructor ?

Comment: It's impossible to tell you without more source code of ItemTool. If toolClass is final, you're stuck.

If it's not, you may be able to do what you want with [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: I've not tried overloading the constructor, although I don't think it would help as I can't overload ItemTool or ItemPickaxe.

Comment: Where is toolClass defined? I don't see it in this class.

Comment: At the bottom just after ================forge start =============

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to use reflection to assign a value to `toolClass`, overriding the private flag.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3239068/3622940